# LED Strip Lights turn on by themselves

Tags: electrical, led, remote-control

In my kitchen I have two sets of under cabinet LED strip lights. These strips have randomly been turning on throughout the day. The strips are both controlled by a remote that signals to separate in-line dimmers that run on the same frequency. Both runs are plugged in to different outlets through AC adapters. The outlets are on separate circuits.

My initial thought was that the remote went bad and was erroneously sending out signals to the dimmers, so I removed the battery from the remote (I had a separate unused remote from the install). This problem has persisted even with the new remote.

I'm wondering if there is some type of RF interference somewhere within the house, but I can't imagine where. I haven't installed anything new in recent days. These lights were working fine for about 8 months before this problem started.

Just as a further clarification, sometimes one strip will come on while the other stays off and vice versa.

EDIT: These are in fact RF controlled dimmer remotes. According to the supplier they use RF Pulse Width Modulation.

Comment: Most of those strips have IR remotes, not RF. Do you know for sure which you have? There may be another device emitting IR signals. Also, some of those devices turn on after a power interruption. Check for that.

Comment: Tthe vast majority of remotes for the last 50 years are IR.  You get a lot of IR light coming in the window, and if clouds or trees are causing the light to pulse, that could randomly be stumbling upon a command code for the LEDs.  Obviously better made dimmers would be more resistant to that, but a huge number of the LED products sold are cheap Cheese from overseas. (and of those, the vast majority are built around the exact same chipset).

Comment: _That_ is what that unknown switch in my basement controls! :D

Comment: See if you can associate the lights turning on with some other event...does it happen when the refrigerator starts?....the garage door opens?....the furnace turning on?  If they are cheap, they may be susceptible to electric 'glitches'.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same thing as Isherwood’s comment.
To identify the type cover the remote and see if it works.  if it will not turn on when blocked it is IR if it works it is RF.

One tell tail sign of IR is lenses exposed on the end this is normally a IR diode clear in color , some have a plastic cover over them and this can not be seen.

Both types can be affected by other remotes and even noisy power these usually have low end decoders compared to a tv or similar remote that have very specific signals.

If the unit is RF you can attenuate stray signals from outside the home with foil. Make a small cup shaped foil around the back it doesn't have to touch it can be like an umbrella and signals from the street will be attenuated and reduce false triggers (a sideways umbrella) this will not stop signals in the house but could reduce them.